# Can't get the value of $routeParams in a controller (AngularJs)

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, routeparams

my config :

```
  .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {


  $stateProvider


 .state('tab.chats', {
      url: '/chats/:id',
      views: {
        'tab-chats': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/tab-chats.html',
          controller: 'detail'
        }
      }
    })


$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/tab/dash');

})
```

my controller :

```
.controller("detail", ["$scope", "$http", function($scope, $http, $routeParams){

   $scope.data = $routeParams.id;
```

my html :

```
<ion-view>
  <ion-content class="ata1">
    <a href="#/tab/dash" rel="nofollow"><img id="logo" src="img/falimda.png" alt="" /></a>

    <div class="clear"></div>


    <div ng-controller="detail">
      {{data}}
    </div>


    <div class="clear"></div>

    <a href="#/tab/dash" class="button button-outline button-light">Back</a>

  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

So  here i'm programming a mobile application by Ionic Framework, and i couldn't solve something.

I'm trying to use this `id` inside my controller by using `routeParams` so that i can use that `id` to pull some data from web but unfortunately i can't reach it inside of my controller. I tried to test and print out my data inside `ng-controller` it didn't work. Can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using ui-router for the routing, but expecting to find the ui-router state parameters in ngRoute's routeParams service. Won't happen.

Use `$stateParams`, and remove the ngRoute dependency from your application, since you're using ui-router.

To fix the other, injection problem explained by the other answer, and avoid to repeat it later, I suggest you stick to the simple declaration or parameters (not using the array syntax which forces you to duplicate all service names), and use [ng-annotate](https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate) to make it minifiable automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Change your controller code as below

```
.controller("detail", ["$scope", "$http", "$routeParams", function($scope, $http, $routeParams){

   $scope.data = $routeParams.id;
```

Comment: changed $routeParams to $stateParams and injected it. It works now thanks!